# Where to place code for audio playback in a SwiftUI app

Tags: swift, audio, avfoundation, avaudioplayer, swiftui

Where is the best place to put code for audio playback in a SwiftUI based app, i.e. not having UIViewController classes? The sound I want to play is initiated by a view, so I'm thinking of putting it into the corresponding view model class. But as a model class is about data, I think there should be a better option. What's the best architecture?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct, the View shouldn't take care of data. And SwiftUI enforces this logic.

You could create a Player class which takes care of playing the audio. And add it as an `EnvironmentObject`, so you can control it with your button in the `View`. You can then do sweet things like binding your play button to show different images depending on whether the player is... playing :)

**Update**
Code has been updated for Xcode 11 beta 4 (`willChange` instead of `didChange`)

```
struct PlayerView : View {
    @EnvironmentObject private var player: Player

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.player.pauseOrPlay()
        }) {
            Image(systemName: player.isPlaying ? "pause.circle.fill" : "play.circle.fill").font(.title).frame(minWidth: 44, minHeight: 44)
        }
    }
}

class Player: BindableObject {
    let willChange = PassthroughSubject<Player, Never>()

    var isPlaying: Bool = false {
        willSet {
            willChange.send(self)
        }
    }

    func pauseOrPlay() {
        // Code that toggles the audio on and off
    }
}
```

Comment: I got this error **Swift5.0** --  BindableObject in the class gives this error **Use of undeclared type 'BindableObject'** and  @EnvironmentObject private var player: Player gives the error **Property type 'Player' does not match that of the 'wrappedValue' property of its wrapper type 'EnvironmentObject'**

Comment: @uplearnedu.com `BindableObject` has been changed to `ObservableObject` see: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/observableobject

Answer (score 0):

Altough the solution from Davide worked, I ended up using the singleton pattern to have global access to my sound player object and actually moved back the triggering of the sounds from the view to the model class.

It looks like this:

```
class Player {
    static let shared = AudioPlayer()

    func pauseOrPlay() {
        // Code that toggles the audio on and off
    }
}
```

I can now call it from anywhere:

```
Player.shared.pauseOrPlay()
```

Comment: An environment object _is_ a singleton with global access, so it is not clear what you did differently. Could you provide some actual code?

Comment: I just used a "normal" class for the Player (i.e. not conforming to a BindableObject) and added a static instance constant of that class. I don't actually need the bindable stuff anymore as I moved the triggering code back to the model and don't need my UI to react on the player state.